# Azure pipeline running dotnet build via docker not reporting errors and warnings

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a Net 7 solution that I am building in an Azure Devops pipeline using Powershell and Docker.

If the build fails for any reason (for example a file doesn't compile), or I have warnings in the build output, these are not reported on the Azure pipeline summary screen. I can see the errors in the Docker part of the build log, and a generic "PowerShell exited with code '1'." error, but no specific dotnet errors, making it difficult to easily see why a build has failed.

I have tried a few different options of outputting errors, but nothing seems to help output the errors properly.

Pipeline output:

[image]

(redacted) log output:

[image]

My pipeline YAML file build step:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Docker: Build/Test/Publish'
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      failOnStderr: true
      showWarnings: true
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        docker compose -f "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/docker-compose.yml" --profile "api" build
        docker create -i -t --name utresults api
        docker cp utresults:/testresults $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        docker rm -fv utresults
```

docker-compose.yml

```
baseapi:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
  profiles: [ 'api' ]
  container_name: Api
  build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Source/Docker/pipeline.Dockerfile
```

pipeline.Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base        
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as build
RUN dotnet build Api.sln \
  --configuration Release \
  --framework net7.0
```

Comment: You can enable more verbose logging by adding variable `system.debug: true` in your YAML pipeline

Comment: Does that output the warnings to the pipeline? Or just show more in the log?

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Comment: I'd say that you try putting each line of the script in a separate task that will at least help you point towards the line that is having this issue.